# How to find the first event that happens in ga4 data

Tags: google-ads-api, google-analytics-4

based on unique keys (ga_session_id || user_pseudo_id) we want to find the first event that started that session. but some records have the same event_timestamp. is there a document that shows which event is earlier?

I couldn't find anything about it in the documents.